# Valid script not working when invoked as npm script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have a Nest JS application. When starting it I want to pass version from `package.json` and last git commit date as environment variables:

```bash
cross-env VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version") LAST_COMMIT_DATE=$("git log -1 --format=%cd") NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch
```

This command works as intended on Windows (and should on Linux too). However, when I put it into `start:dev` npm script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "cross-env VERSION=$(node -p \"require('./package.json').version\") LAST_COMMIT_DATE=$(\"git log -1 --format=%cd\") NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch"
}
```

and start it with `npm run start:dev` it throws a weird error:

```
'-p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: spawn -p ENOENT
    at notFoundError (D:\Dev\tgr\tgrapi\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (D:\Dev\tgr\tgrapi\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at cp.emit (D:\Dev\tgr\tgrapi\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at cp.emit (D:\Dev\tgr\tgrapi\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn -p',
  path: '-p',
  spawnargs: [
    'require(./package.json).version)',
    'LAST_COMMIT_DATE=$(git',
    'log',
    '-1',
    '--format=%cd)',
    'NODE_ENV=development',
    'nest',
    'start',
    '--watch'
  ]
}
```

How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be present on Windows only. It is caused by npm using `cmd` as default Windows shell, which does not support command substitution. Adding `script-shell = powershell` to `.npmrc` file resolves the problem.

For more info refer to this cross-env github issue: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/192